# plotly not installed in shiny-server

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shiny-server

When I use the `plotly` library in a shiny-server I have the following issue:

The app will work correctly using "Run App" command in RStudio Server, but when deployed on the shiny-server:3838 it gives the following error `Error in library(plotly) : there is no package called ‘plotly’ Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library Execution halted`

It seems that `plotly` library for some reason is not installed in shiny-server although it is installed and working for RStudio Server. Does anyone know how to fix it.

I initially thought it could be an issue with my code, but I can actually replicate the exact same issue if I use a code sample provided by plotly-r website [here](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html)

The code to replicate is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "cities", 
    label = "Select a city", 
    choices = unique(txhousing$city), 
    selected = "Abilene",
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  plotlyOutput(outputId = "p")
)

server <- function(input, output, ...) {
  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(txhousing, x = ~date, y = ~median) %>%
      filter(city %in% input$cities) %>%
      group_by(city) %>%
      add_lines()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this on the machine where the shiny server is installed. This installs the plotly package.

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\"
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I still get the same error. I think it might be something to do with different environments in shiny-server and R Studio server.

Comment: The original code example from the plotly website doesn't work when run interactively but does for me after I make the changes. Do you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: no unfortunately it still doesn't work. After digging in the app logs I could see this error `Error in library(plotly) : there is no package called ‘plotly’
Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted` - so it seems that plotly for some reason is not installed in shiny-server but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You have to do `install.packages('plotly')` on the machine where the shiny server is running. Googling for `shiny server install package` gives https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-shiny-server-on-ubuntu-16-04 and suggests a command like this. `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`. Your setup is likely to be different.

Comment: thanks Andrew `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\"` worked! If you want to update your answer with this info I can accept it!

Comment: Thanks although I'd suggest to add the edit right at the top as that is the actual solution, the rest of the answer did not help to solve the issue for me

Comment: Edited to remove irrelevant background.

Comment: can you update your answer? It's missing a " at the end of the command.